# JavaFX CSS Parsing Error

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm getting this error:

> com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser parse WARNING: CSS Error parsing
>   file:/filepath/bin/: Expected LBRACE at [-1,-1]

My code is as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    mainScene.getStylesheets().clear();
    mainScene.getStylesheets().add("//stylesheet.css");
    primaryStage.setTitle("Not Facebook");
    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    primaryStage.show();
    //loadGame(primaryStage);

}

public void loadGame(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(0);
    grid.setVgap(0);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    Text text = new Text("Hello");
    grid.add(text, 5,5);
    Scene gameScene = new Scene(grid, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(gameScene);
}

}
```

> ```
> .root {
>   -fx-background-color: #333333;
> }
> ```

I have searched but no one has the same problem and I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your stylesheet is wrong.

Use

```
mainScene.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");
                               ^^
```

instead of

```
mainScene.getStylesheets().add("//stylesheet.css");
                                ^^
```

Note that you do not even need a single leading `/` to access the stylesheet relative to the root classpath of your application. From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--):

> The URL is a hierarchical URI of the form
>   [scheme:][//authority][path]. If the URL does not have a [scheme:]
>   component, the URL is considered to be the [path] component only. **Any
>   leading '/' character of the [path] is ignored and the [path] is
>   treated as a path relative to the root of the application's classpath.**